# How to assign a model to array of model?

Tags: angular, angular7, typescript-typings

I am trying to assign a model to array of models.  but getting error. how to fix this?

here is my code :

```
export interface ModelSubSystem {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    CreatedBy: string;
    CreatedDate: Date;
    UpdatedBy: string;
    UpdatedDate: Date;
}

const initialState: Array<ModelSubSystem> {
    subsystems: []
};


export function reducerSubSystem(state = initialState, action: ssAction.subSystemTypes): ModelSubSystem {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ssAction.LoadSubSystemSuccess.TYPE:
            return {
                ...state,

            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

from the typescript compiler getting the following error. attached screen shot:

[image: error as screenshot]

Comment: you forgot to add a piece of error information!

Comment: I think it is better to copy/paste error message rather than sharing screenshot. Because for example, imgur is forbidden in my country and also it won't show in search results.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the state with array bracket, it works fine now. here is updated code:

```
export function reducerSubSystem(state = initialState, action: ssAction.subSystemTypes): ModelSubSystem[] {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ssAction.LoadSubSystemSuccess.TYPE:
            return {
                ...state,

            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```